# ubuntu mounting windows raid0 hard disk

Tags: mount

my windows OS crashed and i booted ubuntu from a usb key to try to mount the raid0 HD from windows, i have tried many commands and software (like mount) but the HD dont get mount, any help would be really appreciated.
regards

Comment: Is it a hardware or software RAID setup?

Comment: it is directly seen as raid on the BIOS of the system so i think this makes it a hardware RAID setup?

Answer (score 0):

From the [RAID page on Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Raid):

```
Hardware Raid

Real hardware raid systems are very rare and are almost always provided by a card
such as a PCI card. Your hardware will need kernel level support in order to work
with Ubuntu. You can find out if is is supported without much work by booting a Live
CD. Your array should be visible as a scsi block device and if it has existing
partitions and file systems, mountable.
```

So it seems like if Ubuntu is unable to see your BIOS RAID configuration, then perhaps the RAID controller chip is not supported by the Linux kernel in at least the version of Ubuntu you're using as a Live boot image.

Comment: ok, i can see the two raid disk on the disk utility of ubuntu but can't mount them.

Comment: Likely due to a driver, or hardware issue. RAID 0 is not a good setup to use, as if any of the disks within the array fail, you'll lose access to all the data, as it is interspersed across both. You might be able to recover if you use a Windows recovery image with the drivers for your hardware installed; assuming the disks haven't actually failed. But I think at this point, the question is also no longer appropriate for AskUbuntu, as it is about recovering a Windows installation.

Comment: right, we're installing windows and seeing if we can recover windows installation, if we can't we'll just have to format drive i think :/

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly have a fake raid controller.  You will need to install the `dmraid` package to recognize these.  You can read more at http://wiki.ubuntu.com/FakeRaidHowto