# Quick question: Will a fresh install Ubuntu detect my Raid-0?

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, raid, ssd

I have Ubuntu  installed on an external drive and Windows installed on my primary "C:" drive. I've been dual-booting this way for years.

Recently, I upgraded my single SSD C: drive (where Windows resides) by adding a second SSD in Raid-0. Now, my existing install of Ubuntu no longer detects my C: drive.

**Does Ubuntu not natively detect Raid drives or do I simply need to reinstall Ubuntu?**

Must Ubuntu *also* be on the Raid to detect it?

Comment: What sort of RAID0?

Comment: Related: [How do I properly access Windows software RAID 0?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567432/how-do-i-properly-access-windows-software-raid-0)

Answer (score 1):

First: Upgrade. 13.04 is out of support. Upgrade to 14.04 and you won't have to upgrade again until 2019 if you don't want to.

Secondly, you haven't said what sort of RAID this is.

- FakeRAID (most onboard motherboard RAID controllers) can be detected by `dmraid` but this needs installing. [This is documented](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount%20Windows%20Raid%200%20Volumes%20Howto) and we have [older questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214591/ubuntu-mounting-windows-raid0-hard-disk) about it too.
- Windows *software* raid is something else completely. My Google Fu is lacking this morning but everything I find suggests it can't be read from Linux.
- Real RAID controllers usually work but sometimes need drivers installed. This really depends on the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is not the case as I have 2 servers and I installed Ubuntu on them, one of them asked during installation if I wanted to activate the RAID drivers, so I'm pretty sure your RAID will be recognized.