# Windows volume to Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, mount, windows

I'm trying to move my hobby computer from Windows server to Ubuntu. Unfortunately I get stuck when trying to convert my windows disks that is in raid0 to create one big volume to ubuntu. I want the same setup in Ubuntu and tried to follow [linuxserver](https://blog.linuxserver.io/2017/06/24/the-perfect-media-server-2017/) ([newer version](https://blog.linuxserver.io/2019/07/16/perfect-media-server-2019/)) by using mergerfs fuse to do this. Everything is working down to *"Create fstab entries"* but afterwords I get an error about something called LDM (Logical Disk Manager) and something about NTFS. Is there any other guide that can explain how to convert the drives from windows?

Comment: LDM?  do you mean LVM??   I wouldn't convert myself, and NTFS (NT file system) is a foreign format for Ubuntu so I'd copy the data to a native format where all data is stored and it's far safer. (NTFS stores different metadata without permission detail so isn't ideal unless you want to also setup ACL access & complicate things..)  The LDM though has me lost  (*google suggested you mean `lightdm` but that doesn't relate to file-systems or volume-management*).

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, LDM stands for Logical Disk Manager and I think it is something windows have come up with. Not sure why my drive is this format and I dont know how to change it, when checking the "disk" menu in ubuntu it were named by it. About moving the data and reinstall the drive (if I interpreted it correctly) is not possible as I dont have any alternative storage that would be able to store the data.

Comment: @user68186 I installed Ubuntu. Linuxserver made a new blog were they say that it doesnt really matter (as ubuntu is built upon debian?) and so far there haven't been much difference. Well that is a part of my confusion if I can use NTFS, they mention in the video that other formats is possible too but doesnt go into greater detail.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you have a RAID0 array created in Windows. Now you want to read that array in Ubuntu. You don't want to lose any data on that array. Is this correct?

Comment: @user68186 precisely!

Comment: @user68186 Is the only alternative to format the drives or stay on windows if it is not possible to do?

Comment: Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/488591/quick-question-will-a-fresh-install-ubuntu-detect-my-raid-0/488786?r=SearchResults#488786

Comment: @user535733 Thank you very much! Going to do some more research and try it out!

Comment: You may use LDM tool to access and Backup your Windows RAID - If you can backup it from a Windows machine it is simpler - The idea i want to suggest is: 1:Backup the data 2:Build a new Linux software Raid with MD (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID)